# Entity Framework generation missing an entity

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to generate my entities from my SQL database using the ADO.NET Entity Data Model item and from there using the ADO.NET DbContext Generator.  When I generate my edmx from the database one of my entities seems to be missing in the designer but when I look at the code behind of the edmx I see it in code and when I generate the dbContext the entity isn't generated at all...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is perhaps the table you are missing an entity for a join table for a many-to-many relationship? Those tables don't have a corresponding entity class.

Comment: Yes it is a many to many junction table.  Interesting!  Thank you for your response!

Comment: OK, I've posted my comment as an answer.

Comment: Is there a setting I could switch on that would enable the generation of entities with many to many relationships?  Curious is to why they would not generate them at all...

Comment: No, there is no setting. You can only force this by an additional column, see comment to my answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the table you are missing an entity for is a join table for a many-to-many relationship you don't get an entity class when you create a model from the database. EF recognizes this when the table has two columns which form a composite primary key and each column is a foreign key to two other tables.

EF manages the join table internally and doesn't expose it as an entity. You only have the "left" and the "right" entity with navigation collections pointing to each other. If you add or remove a relationship by adding or removing elements to those collections EF will create the correct INSERT and DELETE statements for the join table when you call `SaveChanges`. But this happens internally and is completely hidden to you.

In other words: Everything is OK.

Comment: So is there no way to query that entity then?

Comment: @Willku: Aside from using direct SQL, no. Because it's not an entity. The join table is a SQL artefact which EF abstracts away by design. You don't need this as an entity. You can do every manipulation of the join table through the navigation collections of the left and right entity. If the join table would have one or more additional columns you would get an entity for the table. But in EF terms this would not be a many-to-many relationship anymore but instead two one-to-many relationships with that intermediate entity.

Comment: Ok, perfect!  After playing around with some Linq I understand now.  Thanks again :-)