# Remove entries from a table that maintains a many to many relationship asp.net mvc entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am writing an application based on an existing database.  I have two tables, a server table and a support table (people who support the specified server).  These tables can have a many to many relationship, and as such I cannot maintain a foreign key within one of the tables pointing to another.

The solution that the person who designed the schema came up with was to add a third table, a server support junction, that has just two columns - ServerID and SupportID, both foreign keys pointing to their respective table.

When I import this database schema into Entity Framework, it gives me the following warning:

```
Warning 2   Error 6002: The 
table/view 'dbo.Server_Support_Junction' does
 not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition
 was created as a read-only table/view.
```

As such, the table does not appear in the edmx model and it does not create a class for the table.

As part of the application, I would like the DBA to be able to delete a server or a support (they leave the company/no longer support a certain server/etc).  Is entity framework smart enough to see that this table is purely relational and will remove any connections when a support or server is deleted?  Or must this be done explicitly?

If it must be done explicitly, what is a workaround for this?  I tried adding a primary key called RelationID to the table, but it yelled at me saying that the primary key was not mapped or something.

Comment: The table should have a primary key consisting of both foreign keys.

Comment: @GertArnold I have done this now, the warning goes away - but after updating the entity framework model, the table is still not viewable in the, nor has a class been generated to represent it.  Is there some way to make it viewable?

Comment: This is [normal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8916016/861716). If you want a junction class, I think you can add a dummy column tot the table, refresh the model and remove the dummy property from the table and the model manually.

Answer (score 1):

Gert Arnold helped to find the solution.   First, a primary key was added to the table consisting of both the Foreign keys, the SQL was:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Server_Support_Junction 
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_ServerSupportJunc PRIMARY KEY (ServerID, SupportID)
```

I then updated the model by opening the edmx, right clicking on the blank space -> update model from database -> refresh -> finish.

To delete the relationship in the controller, the code was as follows:

```
Support support = db.Support.Find(id);
support.Servers.Clear();
db.Support.Remove(support);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Obviously you should do some error checking to make sure the entity was actually found, but that's the gist of it!

Special thanks to [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634914/remove-entries-from-a-table-that-maintains-a-many-to-many-relationship-asp-net-m?noredirect=1#comment58955222_35634914)!